# Scrapy Database only returning one line

Tags: database, scrapy, web-crawler

*I am beginner and looked for the answer on the web but I am not able to do so. Asking it here seems the last resort*

I am trying to receive multiple lines in a table in a database. However its only returning one line. See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXWrl.jpg

If the database functions are left out and its converted into a csv it does show all the data.

Spider code:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

class FundaSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'fundaspider'
    start_urls = [
        'file:///Users/kevinvanhoutum/Dropbox/Shared%20Data%20Mining/FundaOfflineHTML.html'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        yield{
        'zipcode' : response.css('.search-result-subtitle').css('::text').extract(),
        'asking_price' : response.css('.search-result-price').css('::text').extract(),
        'square_meters_house' : response.css('.search-result-kenmerken span:nth-child(1)').css('::text').extract(),
        'square_meters_property' : response.css('.search-result-kenmerken span+ span').css('::text').extract(),
        'rooms' : response.css('.search-result-kenmerken li+ li').css('::text').extract(),
        }
```

Pipeline:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Define your item pipelines here
#
# Don't forget to add your pipeline to the ITEM_PIPELINES setting
# See: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html

import sqlite3

class Funda1Pipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.create_connection()
        self.create_table()

    def create_connection(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect("funda.db")
        self.curr = self.conn.cursor()

    def create_table(self):
        self.curr.execute("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS funda_db""")
        self.curr.execute("""create table funda_db(
                        zipcode text,
                        asking_price text,
                        square_meters_house text,
                        square_meters_property text,
                        rooms text
                        )""")


    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.store_db(item)
        return item

    def store_db(self,item):
        self.curr.execute("""insert into funda_db values (?,?,?,?,?)""",(
            item['zipcode'][0],
            item['asking_price'][0],
            item['square_meters_house'][0],
            item['square_meters_property'][0],
            item['rooms'][0]
        ))
        self.conn.commit()
```

items:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Define here the models for your scraped items
#
# See documentation in:
# https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html

import scrapy


class Funda1Item(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    zipcode = scrapy.Field()
    asking_price = scrapy.Field()
    square_meters_house = scrapy.Field()
    square_meters_property = scrapy.Field()
    rooms = scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

settings:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   'Funda1.pipelines.Funda1Pipeline': 300,
}
```

I think a function is missing that indicates the spider to repeat it for every line or somewhere in the code its shown that it has to stop after one line but I am not sure where. Anyone any idea?

Comment: Your SQL code explicitly picks the first value only of each field (e.g. `item['zipcode'][0]`, that `[0]` means ‘first value from the `item['zipcode']` iterable’). Also, the usual approach in Scrapy is to yield one item per value set, you are yielding a single item with lists of values in every field. Is that intended?

Comment: Im trying the get the "usual approach" to work. So the values of the house per zipcode. This code is the only method im able to make it export like that but in a database and only with a single row in the table. I want it in a CSV file but it does not seem to work.

Comment: If what you want is a CSV file with multiple rows, maybe you can forget abotu the database and rewrite the question about your original issue, show a [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) version of your CSV code, explain what you intent to get and what you actually get.